when tar creates a huge tar file that does not make sense
On RHEL 7-9, on a seemingly good system, with the XFS file system on the root partition, I am trying to

cd /var
tar -cf log.tar log

a du -sh /var/log shows 173M however the tar process will take 10+ minutes and results in a ~129GB tar file.
I have manually done a cp -rp of all the items under /var/log/ to my /data/ NFS mount that is on other system which is RHEL-8.9 and an XFS partition.  This copy was successful, and a du -sh /data/savedlogfolder shows the expected 173M in size.
However, on that RHEL 8.9 system, as root, I then try to tar up this savedlogfolder and after ~2 minutes I have a ~20GB tar file until I Ctrl-C the process.
What is happening?

Likely a large sparse file somewhere in there. Try with du --apparent-size -sh and ls -ldshU -- **/*(D.OL[1,10]) in zsh to spot the 10 largest files (independently of their disk usage).

See also info tar sparse

in case the followup question now becomes "oh! And how do I archive sparse files, then?", I'd recommend mksquashfs log.squash /var/log; common graphical archivers can work with squashfs archvies, it's as easy to un-archive as tar, the Linux kernel can actually mount these archives as file systems (!, much nicer than tar), they preserve sparsity, and bring "nice" archiver features like only storing the data for identical files once, being able to compress (if you want that!) faster than even a good SSD can read data, and there's mature tools for dealing with the files on non-Linux systems.

found a descriptive answer after the mention of sparse files.
Specifically it is /var/log/lastlog and some of the others that cause the problem.
https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/sparse.html

Files in the file system occasionally have holes. A hole in a file is a section of the file’s contents which was never written. The contents of a hole reads as all zeros. On many operating systems, actual disk storage is not allocated for holes, but they are counted in the length of the file. If you archive such a file, tar could create an archive longer than the original. To have tar attempt to recognize the holes in a file, use ‘--sparse’ (‘-S’). When you use this option, then, for any file using less disk space than would be expected from its length, tar searches the file for holes. It then records in the archive for the file where the holes (consecutive stretches of zeros) are, and only archives the “real contents” of the file. On extraction (using ‘--sparse’ is not needed on extraction) any such files have also holes created wherever the holes were found. Thus, if you use ‘--sparse’, tar archives won’t take more space than the original.Files in the file system occasionally have holes. A hole in a file is a section of the file’s contents which was never written. The contents of a hole reads as all zeros. On many operating systems, actual disk storage is not allocated for holes, but they are counted in the length of the file. If you archive such a file, tar could create an archive longer than the original. To have tar attempt to recognize the holes in a file, use ‘--sparse’ (‘-S’). When you use this option, then, for any file using less disk space than would be expected from its length, tar searches the file for holes. It then records in the archive for the file where the holes (consecutive stretches of zeros) are, and only archives the “real contents” of the file. On extraction (using ‘--sparse’ is not needed on extraction) any such files have also holes created wherever the holes were found. Thus, if you use ‘--sparse’, tar archives won’t take more space than the original.

also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126760/what-is-a-sparse-file-and-why-do-we-need-it
